# How do I make a custome directive in angularJs to render some items for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new with angularJs and I want to make a custome directive who will render some items from an ng-repeat. So I have the next custome directive:

```
(function(module) {

module.directive('portfolioList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'util/portfolio-list.tpl.html',
        controller: function($scope){
            var items = [
                {
                    name: 'SomeName',
                    imgLink: 'imgLink',
                    urlLink: 'urlLink'
                }

            ];
            $scope.portfolioItems = items;
        }
    };
});
}(angular.module("ab4.site.util")));
```

And the html code is:

```
<li class="col-md-4 mix" ng-repeat="item in portfolioItems">
    <a href="{{item.urlLink}}" >
        <!-- Portfolio image -->
        <img src="{{item.imgLink}}" >

        <!-- Portfolio name, activated on hover -->
        <div>
            <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

And I want to make a new custome directive who will replace:

```
<a href="{{item.urlLink}}" >
        <!-- Portfolio image -->
        <img src="{{item.imgLink}}" >

        <!-- Portfolio name, activated on hover -->
        <div>
            <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </a>
```

But I don't know how to link the item from ng-repeat with the new custome directive.

Comment: Look into isolate scopes. Essentially, you can bind a variable, like `item` via an attribute: `<foo item="item">`

Comment: @New Dev `ng-repeat` already creates an isolated scope for every item. If OP doesn't need to reuse this directive outside an `ng-repeat`, use of an isolated scope is not needed IMHO.

Comment: @imbalind, `ng-repeat` creates a child scope - not isolate scope. Regardless, there is no disadvantage to having an isolate scope - in fact, in many case, it is what makes a directive reusable. You can definitely have a directive that just "assumes" that there is a scope variable `item`, but it's hardly reusable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use scope inheritance, just create the new directive without an isolated scope (`scope = false` or avoid adding scope) and refer to `scope.item` inside the `link` function or to item inside template.

Comment: Can you give an example, I just started learning angular like a week ago

Comment: I built a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7rcXIojB92bBYFHPEolY?p=preview).

It is based on [this part](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) of Angular guide.